# Java Scoping & Visibility Rules

Tags: java, exception, scope, visibility

I am coming back to writing code in Java after a long gap - most of my coding work over the past few years has been in PHP & JavaScript - and am discovering that I have to work harder to satisfy the Java compiler which is far more rigorous about issues such as variable scope and exception handling.  A piece of code that caused me some trouble is shown below

```
File file = new File(path, fname);
FileOutputStream stream = null;
try 
{
 stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
 stream.write(tosave.getBytes());
}
finally 
{
 try
 {
  if (null != stream) {stream.close();}
  return true;
 }
 catch(Exception e){return false;}        
}
```

This is accepted by the compiler.  However, before I got here I had run into several issues.

- **First attempt: No Catch Block**.  The compiler refused to play ball because it wanted me to deal with the eventuality that the FileOutputStream could not be created.  Ditto for writing to that stream.  I understand the logic behind this reasoning and like it.
- **Second attempt: Catch Block but...**:I was declaring and creating the `stream` variable INSIDE the `try` block. The compiler threw a wobbly again - the `stream` variable was out-of-scope in the `finally` block.

As you will see I have gotten around the issue by declaring `stream` above the `try` block and initializing it to null.

This works.  However, given just how rusty my Java skills are I thought I would ask: Is there a **right way** to write such code?

Comment: You could use try with resource with Java 7 onwards..Just some sugar, still less code

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way to handle such scenarios in modern Java versions (since Java 7) would be to use a [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block that handles all the ugly closing "logic" for you. You'd still have to either catch the exception or propagate it upwards, but that's a relatively small issue. Consider the following:

```
public static boolean writeToFile(String path, String fname) {
    File file = new File(path, fname);
    try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        stream.write(tosave.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Should probably log the exception too
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the various answers - I can only accept one :-).  I was unaware of the try-with-resource block.  I think the last time i did Java it was still in version 6--

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use below code snippet:

```
try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file)){
    stream.write(tosave.getBytes());
}catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}

return true;
```

It's a new feature ([try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)) introduced in Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting hung up on stuff that isn't important.  Yes, in some situations coding try/catch/finally IS important because you actually need to do something to fix an error.

But for opening/closing a file, you don't want to get yourself into knots just to satisfy the compiler. Code Readability is much more important.

How about:

```
String path="somepath";
String fname="somefile";
String tosave="somedata";
try {
    File file = new File(path, fname);
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    stream.write(tosave.getBytes());
    stream.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: I am upvoting your answer because of your comment - _Code Readability is much more important_ - a very valid point.  I should mention though that the context here is a Phonegap plugin for Android that writes to internal storage. I suspect that there is a tangible chance there that the device refuses to let the file be created/written to.

Answer (score 0):

The "right" way is to use Java 7's [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). It has been a long time coming, but it cleans up this sort of boilerplate code really well.

Tough luck if you are stuck on an earlier Java version :)