# Method scope inside Java switch statement

Tags: java, scope, visibility, phonegap-cli

In a rather loose way this question follows on from my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934061/java-scoping-visibility-rules).  The context here is building Android APKs with Phonegap CLI configured, via `build-extras.gradle` to use Java 7.  Here is my code

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, 
CallbackContext cbc) throws JSONException 
{
 Context ctxt = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
 // return doSave(data,cbc,ctxt);
 //the above compiles correctly 
 //doSave is a private method in the same class 
 switch(action)
 {
  case "save":return doSave(data,cbc,ctxt);break;
  //the compiler complains about an `unreachable statement`
  //other case statements ommitted for clarity
  default:cbc.error("Unknown action: "  + action);return false;
 }
 return false;
 //without this return the compiler is upset.
}
```

I am having some difficulty understanding two issues here

1. As far as I can tell even without that last `return` I have defined a clear path of execution thanks to the `switch...default` clause so I cannot see why it requires a return statement there
2. So inside the `switch` statement the private `doSave` method in the same class somehow becomes invisible?

I am coming back to Java after a long gap where I did only JS and PHP.  However, I have done a great deal of Delphi coding at one time so I appreciate the rigor imposed by the Java compiler.  In this instance though it seems to me that it is a bit excessive.  Or perhaps I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: Side note: you are aware, that from a code quality point of view ... that the above is ... well, bad code?

Comment: @Jägermeister - thank you for the tip.  Could you elaborate on what aspects of the code are bad.  As I mentioned I am coming back to Java after a loooong break so I am probably doing several things not quite right.

Comment: Downvoter could you care to comment?

Comment: How you "fetch" your ctxt violates "law of emeter". Then: never do switch statements like that - do not use strings to represent commands (if at all, use enums instead); and beyond that: use polymorphism instead of such switch constructs (otherwise you are putting your logic on 'this command should do that' all over the place - but it should be in one place). If "save" is somehow a constant that has a certain meaning - at least make it a constant. Returning booleans ... normally bad idea. Finally: your names tell me nothing. Dont abbreviate; you are allowed to call a variable "callbackContext"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return doSave(data,cbc,ctxt);break;
```

Your `break` statement is unreachable.

You should remove that statement, as well as the final `return false;` statement, which is also unreachable.

Comment: Ahhh!  Now why did I not realize that!